# Word for feeling threatened or wrathfully jealous because one believes another can be better than they are?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am dissecting my dictionary to no avail for a word which would fit the context of how in Roman and Greek Mythology the mighty gods when challenged in one of their many magnificent talents, even at the subtlest level would become furious with jalousie and thus ruin the mortal who barely even compared for being good at whatever it was they were (when compared to a god) meekly exceptional in, (but when compared to mortals) like gods in.

In fewer words, what is a word which would bring to the thought that jealousy or that feeling of threat to your own greatness by another's trivially opposing attributes?

or,

the destruction of beauty because of one's arrogant blindness which breeds feelings of being threatened.

For example: "why would so majestic a faculty in a mortal's rays be slaughtered by a god's _____"
(A word that would express what I regarded above)

p.s. I apologize for my example being rather poetic but I thought a poetic example would be more fit since I am indeed asking of this for a poem.

Comment: Off-topic but just for clarification, what are a mortal's ***rays***? It sounds like a laser weapon!

Comment: I don't have a single word but, "jealous wrath" comes to mind, Notice that this is distinct from "envious wrath". Envy implies that you ***don't*** have the quality and wish you did. Jealousy implies that you ***do*** have the quality and want to keep it to yourself.

Comment: P.S. I didn't invent "jealous wrath" it is already applied to a god - Jehova , see: *The Jealousy and Wrath of God* 
 http://knollwoodchurch.org/yr2018/h01_jealousy_and_wrath.html

Comment: @chaslyfromUK A poetic metaphor relating the faculty of a mortal to shine like the fiery rays of the sun. Or simply the considered "brilliance" of the talent.

Answer (score 2):

**Pique** is a noun which would possibly work here. [Pique](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pique) means a feeling of anger, especially caused by someone damaging your feeling of being proud of yourself.

The Greeks actually had a specific word for the opposite, the gods' word for the human's attitude of daring to challenge them: **Hubris**.

At some point, the Old English-derived **Wrath/Wroth** took on an optional connotation of explicitly godly fury at another's audacity.

(While now unpopular in psychology, in the mid 20th century, we might speak of **[Malignant narcissism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malignant_narcissism)**).